# When to put "thing" after "the same"

Tags: word-usage

> "Saying nothing" and "not saying anything" mean the same (thing).
>
> "Small" and "tiny" are the same (thing).
>
> "Me not calling you" means the same (thing) as "I failed my mission."

Should I put "thing" after "the same"? Please explain and give more/different instances if there are exceptions.

Comment: I don't understand what your example is supposed to mean (or more accurately, I can't imagine a context where the request would make sense). Why would you ask someone to use "different words" if they mean the same to you? If you didn't understand the first way something was said, the implication is you wouldn't understand a rephrased versiuon anyway, so why ask for it? If you *did* understand the first version, why would you ask for it to be restated in different words? Note that ***mean*** is more natural than ***say*** in such contexts.

Comment: There, I edited it. Sorry.

Comment: You could just use the line as it is , in your song lyrics under *poetic liberty* . However, in a real life scenario, the sentence should be rephrased

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to know what difference in meaning would it make if used in any way.

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense.  Are you saying, "Say the same thing to me, using words I will not understand?"  So, "Go  to the store," becomes, for example, "Journey to the mercantile?"

Comment: Exactly! It also means to me that "just sing along without knowing the meaning of the lyrics" and that "knowing nothing is better than knowing the pain." Does it make sense? Or am I a terrible songwriter? Does it give you some of what I'm saying?

Comment: I've changed my examples; hope they all make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You could leave it as you have it would be easily understood.  Most people will read it as "they say the same (thing) to me," where "thing" is implied.  I don't think it would make for great flow in a song, though.

I think a more natural way of putting this would be something like "Use different words; they're all the same to me" or "use different words; they all mean the same thing."

The main issue here is that you're not really reaching a difference in meaning with the different combinations of words, but some of them would sound wrong to an English speaker.

Regarding adding "all" for emphasis -- yeah, but without knowing the context, I can't really give you any detailed advice on how to verbalize what you're trying to express.

Comment: Hello! I've changed my example. So, could you tell me when should I put "thing."